# Doing groupby and finding the most common group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

here is a sample of my dataset:

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | apple |
| A | banana |
| A | pineapple |
| B | apple |
| B | banana |
| C | grape |
| C | banana |
| C | apple |
| C | mandarine |
| D | apple |
| D | banana |

i want to apply the group by method and list out the most common groups that is present in column 1. For example, my output should produce (apple, banana) as the most common group.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html?highlight=groupby#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) method and then, you can use [count()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count.html?highlight=count#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.count) method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1', 'column2'], data =[['A',  'apple'],
['A',   'banana'],
['A',   'pineapple'],
['B',   'apple'],
['B',   'banana'],
['C',   'grape'],
['C',   'banana'],
['C',   'apple'],
['C',   'mandarine'],
['D',   'apple'],
['D',   'banana']])

df_result = df.groupby('column2').count()
df_result = df_result[df_result['column1'] == max(df_result['column1'])]
```

Output:

```
   column2  column1
0   apple      4
1   banana     4
```

*Edit*: According to the question, you want as output `('apple', 'banana')`. So, continuing with the data above, you can do:

```
result_tuple = tuple((value for _, value in df_result['column2'].items()))
```

Output: `('apple', 'banana')`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('column2')['column1'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
column2
apple        4
banana       4
grape        1
mandarine    1
pineapple    1
Name: column1, dtype: int64
```

Then,

```
s = df.groupby('column2')['column1'].nunique()
s[s == s.max()].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  column2  column1
0   apple        4
1  banana        4
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like `mode`

```
df.drop_duplicates().column2.mode()
Out[156]: 
0     apple
1    banana
dtype: object
```